# bookdown preview with Rmd files in a subdirectory

Tags: subdirectory, preview, bookdown

I am wondering if it is possible to use `preview_chapter()` function with an .Rmd file that is in subdirectory? I've tried it, but got a document without actual text: only section headings and "Placeholder" string where text should have appeared. Once I moved the .Rmd file to the parent (project) directory, it generated the preview correctly. But having all .Rmd files in the project directory makes it look super messy and difficult to navigate through.